# App pool identity versus impersonation identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication, impersonation

I found only one thread relating to this but it did not answer the question.

I'm curious to a link or explanation of the difference between setting an impersonation user via  in the web.config versus setting the application pool identity in IIS. They seem to be independent and am confused on the detailed differences. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using impersonation in the web.config allows you to override whatever identity was configured for the Application Pool the app is running under - it's just a more fine grained method to control identity ( on the app level vs. the ApplicationPool level), so you could have two apps run on the same AppPool, but one of them uses impersonation to use another identity.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the web.config way is ASP.NET specific. If you use other web framework on IIS, then setting application pool identity is the sole option.