# How to connect to MS SQL Server database from ASP using windows authentication specifying a windows user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, adomd.net

I've been trying for just over a month to connect an ASP script here to a SQL Server database
but each time I use this connection string:
    `Data Source=dbServer01;Initial Catalog=POS123;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=domain\usr;Password=pwd;`

It ignores the user I specify and takes the machine name to authenticate the connection, which obviously fails.

so I change the Integrated Security value to False, like this:
    `Data Source=dbServer01;Initial Catalog=POS123;Integrated Security=False;User ID=domain\usr;Password=pwd;`

I then get an error: Login Failed for user "domain\usr" which is impossible because it works when we test the connection with it in the odbc admin app.

I asked the help of a senior and he said it's taking the user name as a database user name, but we need to make it use windows authentication, and specify which user to use.
I remember reading about this a month ago and finding that there was no way to specify a user and password when connecting using windows authentication with this version of ASP.NET.
I'm going to kill myself soon If I can't get this script to connect, someone save me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got at least <del>2</del> 3 options here:

- Create an App Pool on your web server which runs as `domain/usr` and then assign your app to this app pool, and use integrated security. Your connection string will be `Data Source=dbServer01;Initial Catalog=POS123;Integrated Security=SSPI;` - i.e. drop the username and password - these are inherent in the AppPool's identity.
- or (assuming Mixed Mode security is enabled) ask your DBA's to create a new SQL User (just called `usr`) with the same permissions as `domain/usr` and then change your connection string to standard security, with `User Id=usr`
- If you enable impersonation ([here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1206093.aspx/1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826882/application-pool-identity-or-impersonation)), you can use the domain credential without changing the app pool identity. Note the point about securing cleartext passwords, and IME this typically also requires additional configuration to avoid the [double-hop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706580/kerberos-double-hop-in-asp-net-4-0-sql2008r2).

Comment: I ran the default app pool as that user, it's not working, the error persists

Comment: It might be because you've set both `SSPI` and a `UName/Password` - this is incompatable - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi. Also, double check, you've set your app to use the default app pool?. I've added the option for impersonation for completeness, but wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: sweet! I need that impersonation, I know it's not ideal for security, but these are just stats and I've been told to use impersonation regardless

Comment: Sweet!
I found this line in my web.config file: 
`<identity impersonate="false" userName="" password="" />` and changed it to: 
`<identity impersonate="true" userName="MS\Benson" password="MyPassword" />` now it works!